# How to Rid of Large Spacing in CKEditor?

Tags: php, html, ckeditor

[image]

I installed CKEditor, i found it causes large space between lines even though i'm just pressing enter once to move to the next! I have to press "Shift" for every enter to have the breakline! Any idea on how to make it work without pressing Shift?

Line 2 caused by pressing Shift + enter.
Line 3 caused by just pressing Enter.

I'm using PHP

Comment: Or you can basically hit `SHIFT+ENTER` for `<br>`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can set in your config.js to use a `<br>` instead of `<p>` while hitting the ENTER key:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

The available flags are

```
CKEDITOR.ENTER_P (1) – new <p> paragraphs are created;
CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR (2) – lines are broken with <br> elements;
CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV (3) – new <div> blocks are created.
```

Look on the docs for [enterMode](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.enterMode) for further details

---

Expanding on Josepth Silber answer (that he know deleted.. He suggested using `config.autoParagraph = false;` ), IIRC (the Manual is not really clear on what `create wrapping blocks around inline contents` means), the `autoParagraph` config adds a `<p></p>` pair around each inline content inside the body. So, even if you hit Enter on an empty line, it will generate `<p></p>` (or `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, if so configured). The manual suggest leaving that option as it is, though (so set to *true*);

Comment: `+1` It seems your answer is more correct than mine. I must have misunderstood the `autoParagraph` config option. What does that do?

Comment: AFAIK, it adds a <p></p> block around every content. So, if you hit Enter on an empty line, it still writes <p></p>. I update my answer

Comment: CKEditor docs doesn't recommend using "config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;" because of semantic values and correctness. If i use BR mode, will it cause security threats?

Comment: No security threat whatsoever. Simply, line breaks are line breaks, while paragraph have a semantical meaning: they mark different blocks. So, to just go on the next line (which hasn't a real semantical value, just a adds on readability) you use SHIFT+ENTER, while hitting enter means you want to mark the end of a content block and start another. That's why they recommend using <p>, because it's the correct markup in this situation ('because of semantic values and correctness'). Sorry if I didn't explain well but english is not my mothertongue :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I notice when using this setting, It will add 2 sets of `<br/>` for every 1 enter.

Comment: I was calling nl2br, removing that seemed to fix the problem

Comment: Saved my day (y)

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to hardcode this. Open the file sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js in Notepad++ Go to line 22 or search for shiftEnterMode

Change following:

```
enterMode:1,forceEnterMode:false,shiftEnterMode:2,
```

into:

```
enterMode:2,forceEnterMode:false,shiftEnterMode:1,
```

done!

Comment: Why would you go and edit the core files when this can be done in config.js?