# CKEditor paragraph spacing issue

Tags: html, ckeditor

There is issue related to CKEditor paragraph spacing. If I'm typing in ckeditor, it works fine. If I copy paste something from browser, it works fine. But when I **copy paste something from word file, I get large space between two paragraphs**. So I manually need to remove a extra line between two paragraphs. I have searched on internet for solution. And I got some solutions too. But none of them is working for copy/paste from word file. I have tried these solutions.

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098867/how-to-rid-of-large-spacing-in-ckeditor#answer-8098960)
2. [Solution 2](http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Large-space-between-paragraphs#post-46916)

These solution are working fine to solve issue while manually typing or copy/paste form browser. But not working for copy/paste from word file. And I can't understand why this happens. If any one knows the answer, it will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `paste from Word` option on toolbar? Usually copying from MS Word leads to extra markup and it ruins output on web.

Comment: @Justinas. It worked. Can you explain that why I have do `paste from word`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Paste from Word` option on menu bar of CKEditor.

[image: Paste from Word]

That way you will receive MS Word formatted text converted to WEB formatting.

Usually when copying text from some text pre-processors (like Word, Excel...) you will copy some hidden formatting (like inline CSS, additional markup and so on). When pasting to CKEditor directly all these additions are left *as is* and it leads to broken layout, that's why you need to first process this copied text and only than put it in text.